# Access Google Drive Using Google Colab Running an R Kernel (2023)

Tags: r, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to read a .XLSX file stored in my Google Drive using Google Colab R kernel. I'm trying to mount Drive following this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/access-google-drive-using-google-colab-running-an-r-kernel-3736db7835) with no success.

```
install.packages("googledrive")
library(googledrive)
if (file.exists("/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab_ipython.py")){
  install.packages("R.utils")
  library("R.utils")
  library("httr")
  my_check <- function() {return(TRUE)}
  reassignInPackage("is_interactive", pkgName = "httr", my_check)
  options(rlang_interactive=TRUE)
}
```

This code runs without errors. Then I run

```
drive_auth(use_oob = TRUE, cache = FALSE)
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error in `drive_auth()`:
! Can't get Google credentials.
ℹ Are you running googledrive in a non-interactive session? Consider:
• Call `drive_deauth()` to prevent the attempt to get credentials.
• Call `drive_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
ℹ See gargle's "Non-interactive auth" vignette for more details:
ℹ <https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html>
Traceback:

1. drive_auth(use_oob = TRUE, cache = FALSE)
2. drive_abort(c("Can't get Google credentials.", i = "Are you running {.pkg googledrive} in a non-interactive session? \\\n             Consider:", 
 .     `*` = "Call {.fun drive_deauth} to prevent the attempt to get credentials.", 
 .     `*` = "Call {.fun drive_auth} directly with all necessary specifics.", 
 .     i = "See gargle's \"Non-interactive auth\" vignette for more details:", 
 .     i = "{.url https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html}"))
3. cli::cli_abort(message = message, ..., .envir = .envir)
4. rlang::abort(message, ..., call = call, use_cli_format = TRUE, 
 .     .frame = .frame)
5. signal_abort(cnd, .file)
```

And nothing in my Drive:

```
list.files('/content/drive/', pattern = '.xlsx', recursive = TRUE)
```

How can I mount the Drive and read my file with path: `drive/OptimaTEST/data/data.xlsx`